# Issue with resizing disk on VMware VSphere

Tags: virtual-machines, centos7, storage, vmware-vsphere, datastore

I have expanded a virtual disk for a Centos 7 virtual machine to 100 GB size.

[image]

Then I used Gparted to add the unallocated 30GB to the /dev/sda1
partition.

But when I execute  `df -h` the new size of the file system remains in 70 GB.

[image]

how can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: Check this for possible resolution: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=64204